# Plotly Legend Gradiente Color from looping add_trace

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to change the color of Ano in legend to gradient color. In figure example it show years (ano) only with gray color, and it is impossible to know what line correspond to year of in the graphic. So, how to change gray to gradient gray?

However I setting it into the loop and I don't know how to define again witout change the color of last one year (in my case, 2023 has blue color and can't change).

[Link to download the csv data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14MUNcG6A0rta6g6fk7_C2wuE46Z2uQ1Z/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash_bootstrap_templates import load_figure_template

   
df_decremento_municipio = pd.read_csv(
    "dash_estudo/decremento_municipio_202305291512.csv", index_col="view_date"
)

df_decremento_municipio.index = pd.to_datetime(df_decremento_municipio.index)

df_decremento_municipio = (
    df_decremento_municipio[["area_ha"]].groupby(df_decremento_municipio.index).sum()
)

lista_ano = df_decremento_municipio.index.year.unique()[
    df_decremento_municipio.index.year.unique() > 2017
]

df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
for ano in lista_ano:
    df = df_decremento_municipio.loc[df_decremento_municipio.index.year == ano]
    df["timedelta"] = (
        df.index - (df.index.year.astype("str") + "-01-01").astype("datetime64[ns]")
    ) / 1000000
    df["cumsum"] = df.loc[:, "area_ha"].cumsum()

    df_empty = pd.concat([df_empty, df[["timedelta", "cumsum"]]])

grafico_acumulado_tempo = go.Figure()

for ano in lista_ano[:-1]:
    x_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == ano, "timedelta"]
    y_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == ano, "cumsum"]
    data = go.Scatter(
        x=x_,
        y=y_,
        mode="lines",
        name=ano,
        legendgrouptitle={"text": "Ano"},
        marker={"color": "lightgray"},
        opacity=0.7,
    )

    grafico_acumulado_tempo.add_trace(data)

x_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == lista_ano[-1], "timedelta"]
y_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == lista_ano[-1], "cumsum"]
data = go.Scatter(
    x=x_,
    y=y_,
    mode="lines",
    name=ano,
)
grafico_acumulado_tempo.add_trace(data)

grafico_acumulado_tempo.update_layout(
    title="Acumulado Desflorestamento por Tempo",
    xaxis={"title": "Data",
           "type": "date"},
    yaxis={"title": "Área (ha)"},
    xaxis_tickformat="%d-%m",
    modebar={
        "remove": [
            "zoom",
            "pan",
            "select",
            "zoomIn",
            "zoomOut",
            "lasso2d",
            "autoscale",
        ]
    },
    separators=".",
    showlegend=True,
)

grafico_acumulado_tempo.show(config= {'displaylogo': False})
```

See the figure below:

[image]

Comment: If you disable the color settings for the loop process, the line graph will be drawn in a different color for each year. `...,#marker={"color": "lightgray"},`

Comment: Yes, I know. But I don't want random color. I want gray gradient, controlling the color set.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586299/plotly-how-to-make-all-plots-grayscale) is the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by @r-begginners in the comments. This solution shows a different code approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash_bootstrap_templates import load_figure_template
from plotly.colors import n_colors

df_decremento_municipio = pd.read_csv(
    "dash_estudo/decremento_municipio_202305291512.csv", index_col="view_date"
)

df_decremento_municipio.index = pd.to_datetime(df_decremento_municipio.index)

df_decremento_municipio = (
    df_decremento_municipio[["area_ha"]].groupby(df_decremento_municipio.index).sum()
)

lista_ano = df_decremento_municipio.index.year.unique()[
    df_decremento_municipio.index.year.unique() > 2017
]

df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
for ano in lista_ano:
    df = df_decremento_municipio.loc[df_decremento_municipio.index.year == ano]
    df["timedelta"] = (
        df.index - (df.index.year.astype("str") + "-01-01").astype("datetime64[ns]")
    ) / 1000000
    df["cumsum"] = df.loc[:, "area_ha"].cumsum()

    df_empty = pd.concat([df_empty, df[["timedelta", "cumsum"]]])

# Construindo os graficos dos anos passados da série histórica
grafico_acumulado_tempo = go.Figure()

greys_custom = n_colors('rgb(220, 220, 220)', 'rgb(160, 160, 160)', len(lista_ano)+1, colortype='rgb')

for year, color in zip(lista_ano[:-1], greys_custom):
    x_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == year, "timedelta"]
    y_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == year, "cumsum"]
    data = go.Scatter(
        x=x_,
        y=y_,
        mode="lines",
        name=year,
        legendgrouptitle={"text": "Ano"},
        marker={"color": color},
        opacity=0.7,
    )

    grafico_acumulado_tempo.add_trace(data)

x_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == lista_ano[-1], "timedelta"]
y_ = df_empty.loc[df_empty.index.year == lista_ano[-1], "cumsum"]
data = go.Scatter(
    x=x_,
    y=y_,
    mode="lines",
    name=ano,
)
grafico_acumulado_tempo.add_trace(data)

grafico_acumulado_tempo.update_layout(
    title="Acumulado Desflorestamento por Tempo",
    xaxis={"title": "Data",
           "type": "date"},
    yaxis={"title": "Área (ha)"},
    xaxis_tickformat="%d-%m",
    modebar={
        "remove": [
            "zoom",
            "pan",
            "select",
            "zoomIn",
            "zoomOut",
            "lasso2d",
            "autoscale",
        ]
    },
    separators=".",
    showlegend=True,
)

grafico_acumulado_tempo.show(config= {'displaylogo': False})
```